# Что лучше два запроса в базу или один, но с дополнительной обработкой массива?

Tags: php

На сайте выводится список лотов разных художников. Пользователь выбирает лот и переходит на страницу этого лота. Тут отображается информация о выбранном лоте и дополнительно выводится (отобрана) информация о наличии других лотов этого художника.

Какой способ вывода информации будет лучше или они оба приемлемые?

### Способ #1.

Один запрос в базу. Делаем запрос

```
$result_lots = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Для отображения информации по выбранному лоту по id этого лота находим ключ массива этого лота.

```
$a = array_column($result_lots, 'id_lot');
$key_lot = array_search($id_lot, $a);
```

Затем достаем из массива лота необходимо инфу

```
$b = $result_lots[$key_lot];
echo $c = $b->author;
echo $d = $b->catalog;
```

Список других лотов этого автора выводим через foreach, исключая лот, по которому уже дали информацию.

### Способ #2.

Два запроса в базу. Сначала по id лота выводим информацию по интересующему лоту

```
$result_lot = $db->loadObject();
```

и из этого запроса получаем id художника.

Делаем второй запрос в базу по id художника

```
$result_lots = $db->loadObjectList()
```

и выводим через foreach список других его лотов.

Comment: если список полей, которые вы показываете для текущего лота и общего списка одинаков, то смысла в двух запросах, очевидно, нет. Для поиска по массиву сделайте его ключи равными id, используя для этого третий параметр `array_column`

Comment: Ну если учесть, что между первым получением данных (список лотов вообще) и вторым (список лотов конкретного художника) располагается интерактивное взаимодействие - то в общем пофиг. Первый подход нагружает PHP, второй MySQL... С точки зрения кода второй вариант должен быть попроще. Хотя можно модифицировать способ 2 и обойтись одним запросом. Просто именно выбранный лот поставить сортировкой самым первым в получаемом наборе записей.

Comment: Наводящий вопрос: а что будет на странице у очень плодовитого художника у которого тысячи лотов?

Comment: Если предположить, что структура БД автора вопроса примерно такая - `painters`, `lots`, `lots2painters` и при открытии страницы лота, Вы знаете `id` записи из `lots`, то проще было бы одним запросом (естественно с ограничением на кол-во записей, ибо как верно заметил @AlexeyTen их могут быть тысячи) через `leftJoin` соединить таблицу `lots` саму с собой еще раз через `lots2painters` и сразу получить все лоты.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я передаю со страницы лотов id_lot и id_autor. По  id_autor отбираю все лоты художника и достаю из массива id выбранного лота, затем ниже вывожу остальные лоты - все одним запросом. Можно, как написал выше два запроса - один для выбранного лота, другой для всех остальных